# Is using 'thrive faster' incorrect?

Tags: word-usage

In the sentence "For Modern Businesses to thrive faster, they must have a strong online presence.". Should I use thrive faster or just thrive?

Comment: When you say "thrive faster", do you mean "get to the point where they are thriving more quickly"?

Comment: No. I just meant grow quickly.

Answer (score 1):

*thrive faster* has fallen nearly out of use [over the last two hundred years](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(thrive%20faster)&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28thrive%20faster%29%3B%2Cc0).

Nowadays, we tend to use *thrive* without any time or manner modifier. Businesses or babies are thriving or they are not.

We would be far more likely to say "begin to thrive sooner".

P.S. or "for businesses to continue to thrive"

Answer (score 0):

The verb [**thrive** means to flourish or **grow vigorously**,](http://[enter%20link%20description%20here][1]) and it can be applied to something like a business.

(There's nothing "*incorrect*" about thrive faster)

Usage [examples](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/thrive):

- How many businesses out there **thrive** with just 5 percent of their
  customers being women? (Washington Post,Jun 28, 2015)
- It’s dying as a religion, but as a business, it is **thriving**.
  (The Guardian,Jun 28, 2015)